# How much solar can my main and sub panel handle?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, solar

I have a 90A main service and a 200A sub with 200A bus. See pictures attached.

I currently have a 3.9kw solar system on a dual 30A breaker.

How much more solar would I be able to add?

Looking to safely add another 2.8kw of solar (or more).[image: sub panel]

[image: main panel]

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: @Ruskes w not kw. But that's based on the breaker. The question is how much can the panel and utility service handle.

Comment: So I can add another 3.3kw of solar? On another 30A breaker? How does the calculation work?

Comment: Multiply Breaker Amps with 240 Volt (two breakers provide 240 Volt)

Comment: Can you post photos of your main breaker please?

Comment: I added a pic. It's a condo so the breakers are joined 360 total / 4 units = 90A each

Comment: I'm *very* confused now -- are you saying all 4 condo units are on the same meter?!

Comment: No sorry. Each unit has its own meter with 90A main service.  But the mains are joined so I'm not able to upgrader one without upgrading all 4 at the same time is what I was told. The picture I included is just my meter, there 3 others.

Answer (score 1):

1. For back-feeding solar into a panel breaker, the limit is: Panel Rating * 1.2 - Main Breaker. Assuming your main breaker is 90A, that's 200A * 1.2 - 90A = 150A solar breaker, maximum.
2. You can't plan to run breakers at 100% continuously, you must derate 20% so your theoretical maximum on this panel would be 120A of solar or 28.8kW at 240V.

   - On your current 30A breaker, you could feed in up to 30A * 240V * 0.8 = 5760W. To exceed that, you'd need a second breaker (possible with some shuffling but then your panel would be completely full), or you could replace the current breaker with a larger one if upgrading to a larger inverter (individual breakers between panel and inverters would be required if using multiple inverters).
3. Your power company and local laws will probably set a far lower maximum system size, especially if you are allowed to take advantage of net metering. For example, here in MD with BGE, the maximum system size is capped such that the total annual projected production does not exceed the average annual consumption. My house with 400A (CL320) service was allowed only about 17kW of solar based on our consumption.

Comment: I am confused about OP's main breaker.  Does OP have a meter-main with a 90A breaker?  But if so, your answer is spot-on.  Except the 90A service size will also be a limiting factor, so total solar can't exceed 80% of that.

Comment: Made a minor formatting edit, as that seemed to make sense. Undo it if I'm interpreting incorrectly.

Comment: Yes it is a 90A main breaker. I live in a condo. with shared mains (360/4) will post a pic

Comment: I have microinverters so sounds like they could just upgrade the 30A breaker to a larger one to handle the increased solar? I'd only be looking to add another ~2.8kw or so for a total of 6.7kw